# tsq sysfiles.maxsize is showing as -1

Tags: database, t-sql

I am trying trying to increase the max size and growth of a sql database, although when i review the max size under sysfiles for the database and log, the database has a max size of -1. Can anyone explain to me what this -1 represents as I have not found much useful on google so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goodday,

```
select* from sys.sysfiles
```

The value -1 for the maxsize column means UNLIMITED or "File will grow until the disk is full"

Update: [For more information you can(should) check the documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysfiles-transact-sql).